# Android: Where can I put a file in the same app and load it by its path

Tags: android, load

What I'm trying to do is put a file in the app (Like in assets or resource).
But I need to load it by its path "I don't want to use the assets manager .. etc", this is because I'm using a lib need the file name (Not stream).

Note1: I know I can save the file to SD card then use it, but I'm trying to find a way without doing this (Load it directly).

Note2: I tried "file:///android_assets" but it didn't work.

Comment: file:///android_asset/index.html ----use like this.... if your file is in asset folder\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access asset files via File API because it stays in your APK, which is in fact just ZIP file. Files in asset folder are accessed through native asset API where it is handled as ZIP stream. You can see [Asset.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/a982dc05d7ca919c07f50e446549ef9dceadf6bd/libs/androidfw/Asset.cpp) and its method `createFromCompressedFile`.